# angularjs - still confused about "assigning" a property on the scope a value in code

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to modify a model that exists on my `$scope` in a normal function on an Angular controller; But it is not behaving as I expect. I presume this is because there is a specific way you have to assign something to an object that is bound to other controls.

My HTML looks like ...

```
<div data-kendo-grid data-k-on-change="Editor.handleChange(selected, data, dataItem, columns, Model)"></div>
```

My `$scope` looks something like ...

```
$scope.Model = {
    /* propertyes */
};

$scope.handleChange = function(selected, data, dataItem, columns, target){
   target = dataItem; // gets the raw JSON of what was selected
};
```

However, this doesn't update my view.. nor does it properly adjust my model. So I have 2 main issues.

1. How do I assign a value to my `$scope.Model` if only 'Model' is passed through the function?
2. How do I ensure that the updates to `$scope.Model` are reflected on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to pass the target value as an attribute name ? I'm thinking about something like so:

```
$scope.handleChange = function(selected, data, dataItem, columns, target){
   $scope[target] = dataItem; // gets the raw JSON of what was selected
};
```

Called like that (note the quotes around `Model`):

```
<div data-kendo-grid data-k-on-change="Editor.handleChange(selected, data, dataItem, columns, 'Model')"></div>
```

If you didn't succeed to edit your $scope within your *on-change* function, it might be because your directive is creating a isolated scope that inherits from its parent. This can be disturbing with Angular:

> #### scope
>
> If set to true, then a new scope will be created for this directive.
> If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only
> one new scope is created. The new scope rule does not apply for the
> root of the template since the root of the template always gets a new
> scope.
>
> **If set to {} (object hash), then a new "isolate" scope is created**. The
> 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not
> prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when
> creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or
> modify data in the parent scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, both of you, for the answer. This would have driven me mad for so long.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to touch base with you and let you know that this was extremely useful. I've now begun implementing it all over my application.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an Angular problem, but a Javascript issue you have.

If you try this in the console:

```
var a = 3;
var b = 4;
function assign(a, b) {
    a = b;
}
assign();
```

and you test the value of `a`, you'll notice that `a` is still `3`. This is because **JavaScript does not support parameters by reference**. You must change your function:

```
$scope.handleChange = function(selected, data, dataItem, columns, target){
    $scope[target] = dataItem; // gets the raw JSON of what was selected
};
```

and the way you call it:

```
"Editor.handleChange(selected, data, dataItem, columns, 'Model')"
```

and that will work, since you're altering the `$scope` (you weren't before; you were altering a local variable).

Comment: This is actually the first of two major problems, which I've expanded on in another question. I was having a lot of trouble with getting the model to update without hardcoding it, but now that that is solved, I have to fix the second issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495597/angularjs-updating-kendo-widgets-when-the-model-changes

I am really hopeful this can all work together...